# Advantages and disadvantages of a particular definition of rings and subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

My professor defines a ring as a triple $(A, +,\ \cdot)$ such that $(A, +, 0)$ is an abelian group, $(A,\ \cdot)$ is a semigroup and $\cdot$ distributes over $+$. Subsequently, $B\subseteq A$ is said to be a subring of $A$ if:

- $(B, +, 0)$ is a subgroup of $(A, +, 0)$
- $(B,\ \cdot)$ is a semigroup
- if $(A,\ \cdot, 1)$ is a monoid, then $(B,\ \cdot, 1)$ is too.

If $A$ is not unitary, let's agree that the third condition holds; I guess that's the only possible interpretation. Thus, we can observe that, by the above definitions:

- a unitary ring isn't necessarily a subring of a unitary ring
- a unitary subring of a unitary ring has its same unity
- a subring of a non-unitary ring is simply a ring contained in it
- $\{0\}$ is a subring of any non-unitary ring
- the only unitary ring that contains $\{0\}$ as a subring is $\{0\}$ itself.

It appears to me that, even though there is no standard in this context, usually the third condition in the ring definition is left out when *ring* does not implicitly mean *unitary ring*. So my question is: what are the advantages of such choices? What, instead, the disadvantages?

Comment: According to the definition, $\{0\}$ is a subring in every nonunital ring. About advantages and disadvantages: there's no point in using nonunital rings at an elementary level; I know others disagree, but you get a less complicated theory, which also enlightens similarity and differences with groups, where the analogs of “subgroup/normal subgroup” become independent of each other. It's just a lucky coincidence that kernels of group homomorphisms are also subgroups.

Comment: @egreg: OOPS, yeah I messed up: I meant to specify "if the larger ring is unitary".

Comment: @egreg: Anyway, I'll think of your remarks. So you would define _ring_ as _unitary ring_ and _subring_ just like in my post?

Comment: Yes, that's what Jacobson does (and also several authors interested in module theory rather than “pure rings”).